# Can these identities for the Euler-Mascheroni constant be proven?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

I stumbled upon these 4 limit/integral identities involving Euler's constant aka gamma (~0.5772). They appear to be valid based on inspection but I have no idea how to prove them. In addition, I have no idea how these identities connect to the commonly known identities for gamma, or even how any of them follow from connect to each other. Any insight would be much appreciated!

$$
 \gamma = \lim_{x \to \infty } -x+ \frac{1}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{x-t}}{\Gamma(t)}dt}
$$
$$
\gamma = \lim_{x \to \infty } -x+2+ \frac{1}{\int_{1}^{k}\frac{\Gamma(t)}{t^{x-t}}dt}
$$
$$
-\gamma = \lim_{x \to \infty } -x-2+ \frac{1}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\Gamma(t)}{t^{-x-t}}dt}
$$
$$
-\gamma = \lim_{x \to \infty } -x+ \frac{1}{\int_{1}^{k}\frac{t^{-x-t}}{\Gamma(t)}dt}. $$

$$k\in \mathbb{R}, k>1$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand\ga\gamma\newcommand\Ga\Gamma$Concerning the first question, we have to show that
$$g(x):=-x+1/I(x)\to\ga \tag{1}\label{1}$$
(as $x\to\infty$), where
$$I(x):=I_1(h,x)+I_2(h,x),$$
$$I_1(h,x):=\int_0^{1-h} dt\,\frac{t^{x-1}}{t^{t-1}\Ga(t)},\quad 
I_2(h,x):=\int_{1-h}^1 dt\,\frac{t^{x-1}}{t^{t-1}\Ga(t)},$$
$0<h<1$. Since $t^{t-1}\Ga(t)\ge c$ for some $c>0$ and all $t\in(0,1)$, we have
$$I_1(h,x)=O\big(\int_0^{1-h} dt\,t^{x-1}\Big)=O((1-h)^x).$$

To estimate $I_2(h,x)$, note that $\frac1{t^{t-1}\Ga(t)}=1-(\ga+o(1))(1-t)$ as $t\uparrow1$. So, if $h\downarrow0$ so that $(1-h)^x=o(x^{-2})$ (say, if $h=1/\sqrt x$ for $x>1$), then
$$I_2(h,x)=\int_{1-h}^1 dt\,t^{x-1}(1-(\ga+o(1))(1-t))
=\frac1x\,\Big(1-\frac{\ga+o(1)}x\Big)$$
and hence
$$I(x)=\frac1x\,\Big(1-\frac{\ga+o(1)}x\Big)$$
and
$$\frac1{I(x)}=x\,\Big(1+\frac{\ga+o(1)}x\Big)=x+\ga+o(1),$$
so that \eqref{1} follows.

The other formulas should follow similarly. (There should be only one question in one post.)

Comment: Thank you. Can the o(1) term be specified further?

Comment: @Mitch : Of course. This can be done by using more terms of the asymptotic expansion of $\frac1{t^{t-1}\Gamma(t)}$ and then following the lines of the proof. For instance, taking one more term of the expansion, we have $\frac1{t^{t-1}\Gamma(t)}=1-\gamma  (1-t)+\left(-1+\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right) (1-t)^2+O\left((1-t)^3\right)$.

Answer (score 8):

For a sufficiently regular function (such as $\Gamma(t+1)$ or its inverse),

$$\int_0^1 t^xf(t)\,dt=\dfrac{f(1)}{x+1}-\dfrac{f'(1)}{(x+1)(x+2)}+\cdots\;,$$
so your formulas follow from $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$

Comment: Thank you! Is there a comparable formula to the one above for $\int_{0}^{1} t^{-x}f(t)dt$ ?

Comment: When $x\to+\infty$ this integral diverges at $0$ except if $f(t)$ is very special, such as $e^{-1/t^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the first identity,
$$\gamma = \lim_{x \to \infty }\left( -x+ \frac{1}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{x-t}}{\Gamma(t)}dt}\right).$$
The integrand $t^{x-t}/\Gamma(t)$ is sharply peaked at $t=1$ for large $x$. I expand
$$\frac{t^{-t}}{\Gamma(t)}=1+(t-1)(\gamma-1)+{\cal O}(t-1)^2,$$
and evaluate
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty }\left( -x+ \frac{1}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{x-t}}{\Gamma(t)}dt}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(-x+\frac{1}{\int_0^1 t^x[1+(t-1)(\gamma-1)]\,dt}\right)$$
$$\qquad=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\gamma  x+2}{x-\gamma +3}=\gamma.$$

Comment: (i) Why can you truncate the asymptotic expansion by removing the $O(\cdot)$ term? (ii) How exactly do you use the qualitative description "sharply peaked" to use the truncated asymptotic expansion on the entire interval $(0,1)$, rather than just near $1$?